# HP Fortify label SQL Injection on my perfect java PrepareStatement

Tags: sql-injection, fortify

HP Fortify labels SQL Injection on my perfect java PrepareStatement code (see below). After some study, I still can't figure it out. Please help !

```
public class Temp {
    private Connection dbConnection;
    private final String SELECT_ROW_FROM_TEST_TABLE_SQL = "select * from TEST_TABLE where advertisementID = ? and itemID = ?;";

    public Temp(Connection dbConnection) {
        this.dbConnection = dbConnection;
    }

  public boolean checkIfRowExists(String advID, String itemID, String HQ_ID) throws Exception {
      boolean exists = false;
      try (  PreparedStatement statement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(SELECT_ROW_FROM_TEST_TABLE_SQL)) {
        statement.setString(1, advID);
        statement.setString(2, itemID);
        try (ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery()) {
            if (resultSet.next()) {
                exists = true;
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new Exception(String.format("Error executing sql statement: %s", SELECT_ROW_FROM_TEST_TABLE_SQL), e);
    } 
}
```

}

Comment: I also cannot see anything wrong with that statement. Perhaps HP Fortify just assumes that `prepareStatement()` should take a string literal instead of a string variable? That would be pretty naive, but it's possible. You should report this to the makers of HP Fortify. There's a way to contact them here: https://www.ndm.net/sast/fortify

Answer (score 2):

I also don't see any SQL injections in this code.  I would log this against Fortify if you have a reproducible test case.

A few other unrelated comments on this  (I realize this is not meant to be production code):

- Adding a semicolon in the SQL statement is not necessary - and will fail with some DB drivers
- Doing a select * is generally frowned on - if you're looking at the result it makes the code fragile

Answer (score 0):

I see that no SQL injections are part of your code as well. From my experience in working with HP Fortify, I believe Fortify will report an error if it cannot trace the origin of the input for prepared statement. Basically it says input from an untrusted source.

You can try something like:

Try declaring your SELECT_ROW_FROM_TEST_TABLE_SQL variable inside the function checkIfRowExists(parameters...) then HP Fortify should not be able to have SQL Injection label for this peace of code.

```
public boolean checkIfRowExists(String advID, String itemID, String HQ_ID) throws Exception { 
public String sql= "select * from TEST_TABLE where advertisementID = ? and itemID = ?;";
  boolean exists = false;
  try (  PreparedStatement statement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(sql)) {
```